# Confusing sentence from the Economist

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I cannot understand the meaning of this sentence.
From the article titled "[Let England shake](http://www.economist.com/news/britain/21620243-scotlands-independence-referendum-has-opened-cracks-united-kingdom-let-england-shake)" (The Economist Sep 27th 2014), an article about Scotland's independence referendum.

> Nobody asked to design a political system for Britain would ever propose the one it has.

It is so hard.. please help!

Comment: Who would  have ever  proposed the current Britain political system? Nobody!!!

Comment: I am afraid to say this, but I just want to know the "literal meaning" of the sentence. I did not mean to talk about current Britain political system.

Comment: What @Josh61 said *is* the literal meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody [who was] asked to design a political system for Britain would ever propose the one [that] it has.

Answer (score 1):

That if anyone (no matter who) had been asked to design a political system for Britain, they would never have suggested the current one.